# Number of preliminary factors of an integer is O(log(n))

Tags: primes, factors

It is known that every integer N can defined of multiplication of prime factors. for example the number 48 can be written as 48 = (2^4)*(3^1).

How can I proof that the count of the prime factors of an integer N (includes repeating the numbers if needed) is a number of O(log(n))?

(For the example above, log(48) = 5.584... and the count of prime factors is 4+1=5. and 5 <= 5.584 indeed)

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is a "preliminary factor"? What does this have to do with [tag:time-complexity]? What does this have to do with [tag:primes]?

Comment: thanks Jörg W Mittag, i've edited my question.

Comment: You are most likely asking about this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem This is an off topic question and Proof are already here. Ask in math stackexchange. (curtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/users/11622124/noobmaster69)

Answer (score 1):

Logarithm is the inverse of exponentiation. Exponentiation is repeated multiplication. Therefore, the logarithm is an approximation of the number of factors in a multiplication.

The longest possible chain of multiplications, i.e. the highest number of factors will be when you multiply lots of very small numbers. The smallest possible (reasonable) factor is 2, therefore the highest number of factors will be when you multiply by 2 a lot of times.

Multiplying by 2 a lot of times is the same thing as raising 2 to a power. The inverse of that is the logarithm in base 2.

Therefore, the number of prime factors will always be less than or equal to the logarithm base 2.

You don't even need Bachmann-Landau Notation for this, you can give pretty precise bounds, for an integer **n**, the number of prime factors **|(n)|** is: **1 ≤ |(n)| ≤ log<sub>2</sub> n**.